# Round floats in a dataframe to nearest specific float values (rounding to a non integer list)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I have a dataframe like:

```
dict_ = {'Col1':[0.54523, 0.24223, 0.94234],'Col2':[0.992324, 0.274336, 0.245435]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_, columns=dict_.keys())
```

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.54523 | 0.992324 |
| 0.24223 | 0.274336 |
| 0.94234 | 0.245435 |

And I want only to have the specific values `0.25, 0.5, 1.0`, rounding the original `df` dataframe to the nearest possible number on the specific values.

So, I want `df` to become:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 1.0 |
| 0.25 | 0.25 |
| 1.0 | 0.25 |

How to do this in python (preferably in a pandas dataframe)?

Comment: *"round-to-nearest-quarter"* This is equivalent to multiplying by 4, rounding, then dividing by 4.

Comment: `0.0` and `0.75` are not part of the list, but I get your point in case of an uniform distribution. In that case it would be the best approach.

Comment: Oh, non-uniform quantization bins, I hadn't noticed that. But you can still handle it by multiplying by 4, quantizing, then dividing by 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use numpy broadcasting to calculate the absolute differences between each value in `Col1` and `Col2` with the values from array `[0.25, 0.5, 1.0]`  then use **[`.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html)** to find the index of closest values:

```
c = ['Col1', 'Col2']

a = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 1.0])
idx = np.abs(df[c].values[:, :, None] - a).argmin(axis=-1)
df[c] = a[idx]
```

Result:

```
   Col1  Col2
0  0.50  1.00
1  0.25  0.25
2  1.00  0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

method1:

if the value is fix as [0.25, 0.5, 1.0], then use:

```
np.round(df/0.125, 0) * 0.125
```

---

method2:

1. use `pd.cut` as `bins` add the mean values of every element in the list `[0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]`, so the `bins` is `[0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]`.
2. and the `lable` set as `[0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]`

```
bins = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]
labels = sorted(bins + bins)[1:-1]
print(labels) # [0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]

obj = pd.Series(bins)
bins += ((obj + obj.shift(1))/2) .dropna().tolist()
bins.sort()
print(bins) # [0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]

dfn = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    dfn[col] = pd.cut(df[col], bins=bins, 
                      labels=labels, 
                      ordered=False)

print(dfn)

       Col1  Col2
    0  0.50  1.00
    1  0.25  0.25
    2  1.00  0.25
```